Sympy: Nonlinear term error when using linear_eq_to_matrix
I am currently trying to implement a program that combines me some symbolic linear differential equations into one system of differential equations.
Thereby, I faced the problem that I get some error that I have a nonlinear expression and I haven't an idea where it comes from.
To present the problem, I implemented an excerpt of the code:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as syp
syp.init_printing()
#Matrices
AM = syp.MatrixSymbol('{A_{M}}', 2, 2)  
LM = syp.MatrixSymbol('L_M', 2, 1)      
BM = syp.MatrixSymbol('B_M', 2, 1)      

C = syp.Matrix([[1, 0]])               

#Elements of the matrices
LM0, LM1 = syp.MatrixSymbol('L_M0', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('L_M1', 1, 1)
BM0, BM1 = syp.MatrixSymbol('B_M0', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('B_M1', 1, 1)
AM00, AM01, AM10, AM11 = syp.MatrixSymbol('A_M00', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('A_M01', 1, 1),                         syp.MatrixSymbol('A_M10', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('A_M11', 1, 1)

#Variables
xMd = syp.MatrixSymbol('xhatdot_M', 2, 1) 
xM = syp.MatrixSymbol('xhat_M', 2, 1) 
uM = syp.MatrixSymbol('u_M', 1, 1) 
yd, y = syp.MatrixSymbol('ydot', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('y', 1, 1) 
iG, iM, iS, iL = syp.MatrixSymbol('i_G', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('i_M', 1, 1),     syp.MatrixSymbol('i_S', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('i_L', 1, 1)
uZd, uZ = syp.MatrixSymbol('\dot{u}_Z', 1, 1), syp.MatrixSymbol('u_Z', 1, 1) 
uZMd = syp.MatrixSymbol('{\dot{\hat{u}}_{Z,M}}', 1, 1)
uZM= syp.MatrixSymbol('{\hat{u}_{Z,M}}', 1, 1)
iLMd = syp.MatrixSymbol('{\dot{\hat{i}}_{L,M}}', 1, 1)
iLM = syp.MatrixSymbol('{\hat{i}_{L,M}}', 1, 1)


yM = syp.MatrixSymbol('y_M',1,1)
yS = syp.MatrixSymbol('y_S',1,1) 

#Definition of the dynamics
eqMdyn = syp.Eq((AM - LM * C) * xM + BM * uM + LM * y, xMd)

display(eqMdyn)
A, b = syp.linear_eq_to_matrix([eqMdyn], [xM, y, uM]) # until here, it is working
display(A)


#Replacing uM by iM
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(uM, iM)
#Replacing y by uZ
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(y,uZ)


#Replacing the vectors by their components
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(xMd, syp.BlockMatrix([[uZMd],[iLMd]]))
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(xM, syp.BlockMatrix([[uZM],[iLM]]))

#Replacing the matrices by their components
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(AM, syp.BlockMatrix([[AM00, AM01],[AM10, AM11]]))
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(LM, syp.BlockMatrix([[LM0],[LM1]]))
eqMdyn = eqMdyn.subs(BM, syp.BlockMatrix([[BM0],[BM1]])) 


display(eqMdyn)

A, b = syp.linear_eq_to_matrix([eqMdyn], [uZM, iLM, uZ, iM])

This results in
nonlinear term: Matrix([
[{\hat{u}_{Z,M}}],
[{\hat{i}_{L,M}}]])

However, I do not see the nonlinearity.
A second, maybe related question is: How can I force the solver to reduce the multiplication AM-LM*C to one matrix containing the results of this term?
